# copy and update sql server data while keeping table data integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table in which the schema looks like this

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
  ,[key]
  ,[value]
  ,[created]
FROM [ESO].[dbo].[tblKeyValueStore]
```

I want to end up making a copy of every row in which it contains the key = "links:applications"  and create NEW records (not update) in which the addtional new keys will contain the same values , but the newly created keys are instead  "links:boa"

Seems to me there are many ways to do this, but some ways are extremely tedious.  I prefer not to be messing around with SSMS GUI with Select and copy and paste as i will end up wanting these new records also in script to then be able to insert them insert production database

1. Should I export the data as a script where key="links:applications" ,  then run an update on that data to change the script to have the varchar string of "links:boa"  and then do an insert?

I'm thinking it seems a bit messy to do that as the export script won't be really data that in then easily able to update and insert back into this table will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `select` and `insert` it directly, but i assume `[id]` is autoincrement

```
INSERT INTO [ESO].[dbo].[tblKeyValueStore] ([key], [value], [created])
SELECT 
   'links:boa' [key]
  ,[value]
  ,[created]
FROM [ESO].[dbo].[tblKeyValueStore]
WHERE [key]='links:applications'
```

Comment: Yes,  id is autoincrement,  so would this select into insert  work ?

Comment: also  created is Default Value =   (getutcdate())

Comment: I believe that you want to leave created to its original value not to the date/time when you insert the edited record..so the code above will work